# Split filename with multiple variables

Tags: ansible

We have sets of config files that end in the environment extension (eg. app.properties.prod, app.properties.dev, db.prod, db.dev, and so on).  I am passing Ansible a variable named environment=prod with the intention of pulling just the files ending in a .prod extension from a filerepo and then need to drop that suffix from the filename so it ends up as app.properties

Something like this will find the correct files:

```
(env = prod)

copy:
  src: "{{item}}"
  dest: /app/homedir
with_fileglob:
  - /go/to/my/repo/*{{env}}
```

This copies the correct files to my `/app/homedir`

However, trying to drop the `env` file extension does not work

```
copy:
  src: "{{dropsuffix}}"
  dest: "{{dropsuffix.split('.{{env}}')[0] }}"
with_fileglob:
  -/app/homedir/*.{{env}}
loop_control:
  loop_var: dropsuffix
```

However removing the `{{env}}` and just adding the text 'prod' will work

```
dest: "{{dropsuffix.split('.prod')[0] }}"
```

I'm assuming there is some jinja formatting issue with the variable nested in there, I've tried various permutations and I'm stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use [regex_replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) filter to remove the extension.

```
- copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/app/homedir/{{ item|basename|regex_replace(regex, replace) }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', '/go/to/my/repo/*.' ~ env, wantlist=True) }}"
  vars:
    regex: "{{ '^(.*)\\.' ~ env ~ '$' }}"
    replace: "{{ '\\1' }}"
```